# How to align datepicker icon appearing below the datepicker textbox properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I want the datepicker icon to appear just after the datepicker. However, the datepicker icon appears below the datepicker. I have attached a JSFiddle. [Fiddle for datepicker](https://jsfiddle.net/m3b2zdqL/)

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "-100:+0",
          showOn: 'button',
          buttonText: 'Show Date',
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          maxDate: 0
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<body>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>DOB :</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" name="dob" value="" id="datepicker" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

I tried getting the datepicker button aligned to the textbox in many ways but failed. I have to get the datepicker button aligned to the textbox.

It works perfectly on JSFiddle. However, if you run it on Chrome. You will notice that datepicker button appears below the text box. How to align it to text-box?

Comment: display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;

Answer by Shailesh works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to style did the job..

```
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align: middle; 
width: 90%; 
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input.hasDatepicker {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 21px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 21px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 21px);
    width: -ms-calc(100% - 21px);
    width: calc(100% - 21px);
}
```

**Add the above css**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "-100:+0",
          showOn: 'button',
          buttonText: 'Show Date',
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          maxDate: 0
        });
      });
```

```css
input.hasDatepicker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 21px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 21px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 21px);
  width: -ms-calc(100% - 21px);
  width: calc(100% - 21px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<body>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>DOB :</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" name="dob" value="" id="datepicker" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change below CSS

```
.form-control {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  color: #555;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s  ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Dont you think it will affect all my form-controls? ..

I would rather suggest the answer in the above comment.